# What is a noun of direct address in French?

Tags: grammaire, noms

I know I heard a term for nouns of direct address when I did French grammar in HS, but I can't for the life of me think what we call one in French. Examples:

> **Jean,** pourrais-tu me donner le dictionnaire ?

> Écoutez mes paroles, **les amis.**

> **Marie,** tu viens de me le donner.

Sorry, I know it's a really basic question but it's escaping my brain right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring to is known more technically as "vocative case". If you look up "direct address" on Wikipedia you'll be redirected.

From there, as a Latinate word, the translation is pretty direct: [le vocatif](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocatif).

You could also "reverse engineer" a more word-for-word translation for the original term by using that page's French description of the term:

> l'interpellation directe *ou* l'invocation d'une personne

(The trick I often use for such things is to look up the English on Wikipedia and then use the language switcher / list of other languages to find the same article on French Wikipedia. This method seems to be pretty reliable for finding standard equivalents for technical jargon.)

Comment: Ah same as Latin and Greek awesome thanks!